# User autoloader to include classes

Tags: php, class, autoload

I am having a directory which look like this:

[image: Directory Schema]

in the file `inc/class/autoload.php`, I have written a code to include automatically all the classes(`Cart.class.php` and `Database.class.php`).

**autoload.php**

```html
<?php

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

function autoload($class){
    require_once($class.'.php');
}
```

The problem is that when I include the file `inc/class/autoload.php` in `inc/templates/header.php` or `products/index.php`, the class `Cart.class.php` and `Database.class.php` cannot be found.

To include the autoloader, I use:

1. `require_once('../inc/class/Database.class.php');` in `products/index.php`
2. `require_once('../class/Database.class.php');` in `inc/templates/header.php`

Kindly help me fix this problem.

Comment: Your autoload function does not seem to bother with the `.class` suffix nor the concrete subdirecory holding your files (and no, you haven't mentioned the include_path being prepared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in autoload too include the files from the same location where your autoload.php is:

```
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/{$class}.class.php");
```

and this only once in index.php

```
require_once('../inc/class/autload.php');
```

Each PHP script runs in the current location, so all files that are included, have the same working location. So if you call `/products/index.php` the working folder is `/products`. And with `dirname(__FILE__)` you get the current folder from the file that is calling the script. Here `../inc`. For more Information lookup: Current Working Dir - How to change folder PHP? Absolute and Relativ Pathes in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Can you explain it better to me? Normally the files are in the same folder so I just have to specify the name of the file. But how come I have to mention the name of the folder where the autoload is ?